# In Sharepoint online, Multiline line of text column filter using RestAPI

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I tried to search the value in one particular column of the list using RestAPI. (Sharepoint Online). I couldn't able to filter the list because column type is Multiline of text. So i posted my doubt here

[Mulitiline of text column not used to filter particular word from list using rest API filter query in sharepoint online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/260646/mulitiline-of-text-column-not-used-to-filter-particular-word-from-list-using-res)

And i followed the answer which was provided by #LZ_MSFT. Now i am facing the issue in console. Here i have attached the issue screenshot. Please suggest me the solution.

[image: Console Error Message]

Comment: If you click on chevron beside error in console, it will show file name, method and line number. Kindly check for that to get better idea about your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I got the answer please check it here [https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/260646/mulitiline-of-text-column-not-used-to-filter-particular-word-from-list-using-res][1]